# Render videos in CKEditor (WYSIWYG)

Tags: media, files

I am using Media Module 2.x.alpha2 + File Entity Alpha2

Using WYSIWYG (CKEditor)'s Add Media button I can upload videos but there is no proper file formatter to display it in the page, all I see is:

```
<source type="video/mp4" src="http://path/sites/default/files/myfile.mp4"></source>
<source type="video/ogg" src="http://path/sites/default/files/SSA50002.ogv"></source>
```

How can I properly rewrite the code to have a proper formatter etc:

```
<div id="video_lightbox_myvideo" class="lightbox" style="display: none;">
<embed name="player_1" id="player"
          type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
          pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
          width="800" height="600"
          src="http://path/wel/players/jwflvplayer/player.swf"
          allowfullscreen="true"
          allowscriptaccess="always"
          flashvars="file=' . $video_path . '&fullscreen=true&image=' . $video_preview . '&skin=http://path/wel/players/jwflvplayer/skins/mainley.swf">
          </embed>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can use [Wysiwyg Media Embed](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_mediaembed) module to embed videos.

> This is an integration of the CKEditor MediaEmbed plugin for the
>   Wysiwyg module.